# iphone uitablecellview overflow

Tags: iphone, uitableview

Is there a way to hide the overflow in a `UITableViewCell`? I have a custom cell view, that I load into the table, where some of the information is supposed to be hidden on load, and then each row will expand when clicked.

Right now, I'm returning height `30` for my row, which is the height of the cell header, but the buttons and text that are supposed to be hidden just overflows and is placed on top of the headers below.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you can use clip subviews(`cell.contentView.clipsToBounds = YES`), it's probably best if you add the subviews when you need to expand and remove the subviews the cell collapses. It should increase performance.

Comment: The specific to to use for clipping would be `cell.contentView.clipsToBounds = YES`.

Answer (score 0):

There's a property on UIView "clips subviews?".

If you set this value TRUE for the cells, it should stop the buttons from overflowing - you can do it either in IB, or in code programmatically (slightly different name in code).

HOWEVER ... this may NOT be what you want. Depends on the effect. Last time I did what you're doing, I used clipsubviews.

Usually, the correct way to hide your buttons etc is the UIView property "hidden" (or the other one - "enabled").

But that might mess with your animations - depends how you're animating the click-to-expand.